# ECG App not appearing on Apple Watch (Region: INDIA)

Tags: apple-watch

Recently, Apple launched ECG Feature for India quite recently with the latest generation of WatchOS. I do not seem to have it on my Apple Watch Series 4 even after updating it to the latest version of WatchOS.

How do I go about troubleshooting to get the ECG app?

iPhone is on the latest version of iOS.

Apple Website - https://www.apple.com/in/watchos/feature-availability/#branded-ecg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest updated version of WatchOS 6.0, it seems to be fixed for my Apple Watch. Somehow the activation in Saudi Arabia has triggered the ECG feature to appear.

```
watchOS 6.2.5 includes new features, improvements and bug fixes: 

 - ECG app on Apple Watch Series 4 or later now available in Saudi
   Arabia 
 - Irregular heart rhythm notifications now available in Saudi
   Arabia
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you also update your iPhone to the latest version of iOS as well. The ECG feature is on the iPhone and it needs to be enabled there 1st.

**Set up the ECG app**

1. Open the Health app on your iPhone.
2. Follow the onscreen steps. If you don't see a prompt to set up, tap Browse > Heart > Electrocardiograms (ECG) > Set Up ECG App.
3. After you complete set up, open the ECG app to take an ECG.

[image]

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208955

Comment: I do not see "ECG" under Heart on the Apple Watch app on iOS.

Comment: It won't be there unless you go to the Health app on the iPhone 1st. Have you tried going to Browse > Heart > Electrocardiograms (ECG) > Set Up ECG App in the Health app?

Comment: I have checked it under the Health App as well. It doesn't say setup up Apple Watch when I go under Heart > ECG.

Comment: I have already checked the Apple support page before asking this question.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: The version is iOS 13.2

Comment: It won't say set up Apple Watch it should say "set up ECG App".

Comment: Ugh. Yes, "Set up ECG". It does not say that.

Comment: Is there a Heart option in the Apple Watch app on your iPhone?